# Merge two CSV files

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I want to merge two CSV files, which have same header into one CSV file.
I have two such files as shown below i.e `DevData.csv` and `ProdData.csv` with same `cfname` and different `ID`s

```
    ID                   cfname
    -------------------- -----------------------------------
                   10201 Risk ID
                   10202 Issue ID
                   10203 Dependency ID
                   10204 Server ID
                   10205 Parent Application ID
                   10206 Application Service ID
                   10207 Application Supportability
                   10208 Application Compatibility
                   10300 Application Status
                   10301 Contact ID Type 2
                   10302 Contact ID Type 3
                   10303 Contact ID Type 4
                   10304 Business Service Manager
                   10308 Server Location Name:
                   10309 Rack Position:
                   10310 Rack Number:
                   10311 Data Centre
                   10312 Server Group
(14 rows affected)
```

I want to create new CSV in the following format:

```
DevID                ProdID cfname
-------------------- ------ -----------------------------------
               10201 201    Risk ID
               10202 202    Issue ID
               10203 203    Dependency ID
               10204 204    Server ID
               10205 205    Parent Application ID
               10206 206    Application Service ID
               10207 207    Application Supportability
               10208 208    Application Compatibility
               10300 209    Application Status
               10301 210    Contact ID Type 2
               10302 211    Contact ID Type 3
               10303 212    Contact ID Type 4
               10304 213    Business Service Manager
               10308 214    Server Location Name:
```

Following is my current code, but it exports data of first file and below it the data of next file.

```
function Merge-CSVFiles {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [string[]]$CSVFiles
    )

    $Output = @();
    foreach ($CSV in $CSVFiles) {
        if (Test-Path $CSV) {
            $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($CSV)
            $temp = Import-CSV -Path $CSV |
                    select ID, cfname, ID, cfname, @{Expression={$FileName}}
            $Output += $temp
        } else {
            Write-Warning "$CSV : No such file found"
        }
    }
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
    Write-Output "$OutputFile successfully created"
}

Merge-CSVFiles -CSVFiles "C:\Users\ECSAdmin\Desktop\Proddata.csv", "C:\Users\ECSAdmin\Desktop\Devdata.csv" -OutputFile "C:\Users\ECSAdmin\Desktop\Mergedata.csv"
```

Comment: "*two csv files, which have same header*" - but `ID, cfname` and `DevID, ProdID, cfname` are not the same?

Comment: DevID and ProdID will come in output CSV file.I have executed the same query on development (creates Devdata.csv ) and production(creates Proddata.csv ) db which create same output with different ID.So I want to merge these two file with ProdID , DevID and cfname as headers in the final output csv file.

Comment: You need to add header.

   `import-csv -path ".csv" -Header DevID,ProdID,Cfname`

and merge two csv

    `$merged = $csv1 + $csv2
    
    $merged | Select -Property * -Unique`

Comment: Your input data looks like the output of a database query (DB2?), not like an actual CSV (Comma Separated Values). You'd need to write your own parser to handle that. Also, what you're trying to do is not concatenation (appending file B to file A), but merging the files (or "joining" in database terms). If you're working with a database it would be best to do the join in your database, then export the result to a CSV. If that's not possible, you need code that adds IDs from file B by matching the `cfname` values. A hashtable lookup is the usual way to achieve that.

Comment: Or is there any way I can get the result in proper csv format?

Following is the command I have used to get the result from database
sqlcmd -S <ServerIP> -d JIRAD -E -Q "SELECT [ID] ,[cfname]
        FROM [JIRAD].[dbo].[customfield] where [CUSTOMFIELDTYPEKEY]='com.valiantys.jira.plugins.SQLFeed:com.valiantys.jira.plugins.sqlfeed.customfield.type'" | out-file "C:\Users\d-test\Desktop\data2.csv"

Comment: With [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) you need to add the parameters `-W` and `-s","` (uppercase "W" and lowercase "s") to create actual CSV output. The command can also write to a file directly (`-o`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have tried adding these parameters as well
sqlcmd -S 10.1.60.106 -d JIRAD -E -Q "SELECT [ID] ,[cfname]
        FROM [JIRAD].[dbo].[customfield] where [CUSTOMFIELDTYPEKEY]='com.valiantys.jira.plugins.SQLFeed:com.valiantys.jira.plugins.sqlfeed.customfield.type'" | out-file "C:\Users\d-test\Desktop\data.csv" -s"," -W 700

But it throws me an error saying terminator missing, there's some minor mistake I have done, but unable to figure where.

Comment: Start with understanding the difference between `sqlcmd` and `Out-File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* do a nested foreach loop over the two sets, but two avoid the execution time growing exponentially relative to the input size, a better strategy would be to load one set into a hashtable (using the common property `cfname` as key) and then loop over the other one and concatenate the two:

```
$DevData = @'
ID,cfname
10201,Risk ID
10202,Issue ID
10203,Dependency ID
10204,Server ID
10205,Parent Application ID
10206,Application Service ID
10207,Application Supportability
10208,Application Compatibility
10300,Application Status
10301,Contact ID Type 2
10302,Contact ID Type 3
10303,Contact ID Type 4
10304,Business Service Manager
10308,Server Location Name:
10309,Rack Position:
10310,Rack Number:
10311,Data Centre
10312,Server Group
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

$ProdData = @'
ID,cfname
201,Risk ID
202,Issue ID
203,Dependency ID
204,Server ID
205,Parent Application ID
206,Application Service ID
207,Application Supportability
208,Application Compatibility
209,Application Status
210,Contact ID Type 2
211,Contact ID Type 3
212,Contact ID Type 4
213,Business Service Manager
214,Server Location Name:
'@ |ConvertFrom-Csv

# throw one set into a hashtable
# we can use this as a lookup table for the other set
$ProdTable = @{}
foreach($line in $ProdData){
    $ProdTable[$line.cfname] = $line.ID
}

# Output the DevData with the appropriate ProdData value
$DevData |Select-Object @{Label='DevID';Expression={$_.ID}},@{Label='ProdID';Expression={$ProdTable[$_.cfname]}},cfname |Export-Csv .\new.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathias 
This works perfectly fine if I copy paste the CSV data into the variables as you have mentioned, but not when I perform Import-CSV. 
I can't copy paste the data all the time, Is there any way to achieve same thing using import-csv?

Comment: @Supriya If the csv files has the same contents as the strings in my example, the output from `Import-Csv` will be the same as what you see from `ConvertFrom-Csv` above

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple pipeline of commands:

```
Out-file -FilePath '.\csv3.csv' -InputObject "ProdID,ID,cfname"; ForEach($CFName In $Csv1) { $Csv2.Where({$_.cfname -eq $CFName.cfname}) | %{ "$($_.ProdID),$($CFName.ID),$($_.cfName)" } | Out-File .\csv3.csv -Append}
```

Where I assumed that Csv1.csv is the first file with ID and cfname columns and second file Csv2.csv has ProdID and cfname column. This will produce third file csv3.csv with merged contents

Answer (score 0):

Since you're exporting data from SQL Server with [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) you need to add the parameters `-W` and `-s","` to have your command create actual CSV output:

```
sqlcmd -S server -d db -E -Q "query" -W -s"," -o output.csv
```

Once you have actual CSV files you can process them like this:

```
# create a hashtable from the second CSV, so you can look up IDs by the
# values in the "cfname" column
$proddata = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\ProdData.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $proddata[$_.cfname] = $_.ID
}

Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\DevData.csv' |
  Select-Object @{n='DevID';e={$_.ID}},
                @{n='ProdID';e={$proddata[$_.cfname}}, cfname |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\merged.csv'
```

This does assume your `ProdData.csv` contains only `cfname` values that also appear in `DevData.csv`, and that your `cfname` values are unique at least in `ProdData.csv`. A two-way merge is more complicated, since you need to check whick keys in `$proddata` don't exist in `DevData.csv` and append them accordingly. If your `cfname` values aren't unique you'll be unable to align the records.

Comment: It prints the following error in output.csv file
`Sqlcmd: '”': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.`

Comment: That looks like a typographic quote. Do not use them in code.

Comment: It worked.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more thing, as the CSV file created is in CSV (Macintosh) format. I wanted it to be in CSV (Comma dilimited).Is there any parameter to get it in Comma Dilimited format?